# Power BI Query Error: The column either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table available in the current context

Tags: powerbi, lookup, dax, powerquery

I have a table having customer transactions. I need to create a new column where, for each row:

1. If its the first appearance of a 'customer id', it will have "Onboarding"
2. If its the last appearance of a 'customer id', it will have "Offboarding"
3. The rest will be "Existing"

So following is the DAX Code i tried out:

```
Customer Churn =
IF (
    Book[Date]
        = LOOKUPVALUE ( Book[Date].[Date], Book[customer id], FIRSTDATE ( Book[Date] ) ),
    "Onboarding",
    IF (
        Book[Date]
            = LOOKUPVALUE ( Book[Date].[Date], Book[customer id], LASTDATE ( Book[Date] ) ),
        "Offboarding",
        "Existing"
    )
)
```

But i am getting the following error:

```
The column 'Book[customer id]' either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table available in the current context.
```

Can't think of using RELATED() as I'm referring the same table.

Where is the issue?
Any workaround if it's not possible to code it this way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help I got the solution. Refer to [dax/lookupvalue-function-dax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/lookupvalue-function-dax?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you will find out the errors in the original script. The search_columnName and search_value are a pair.

```
LOOKUPVALUE( <result_columnName>, <search_columnName>, <search_value>[, <search_columnName>, <search_value>]…)
```

So the formula can't return the right result.

```
LOOKUPVALUE ( Book[Date].[Date], Book[customer id], FIRSTDATE ( Book[Date] ) )
```

**Solution:**

```
Customer Churn =
   VAR startDate =
      CALCULATE ( FIRSTDATE ( Book[Date] ), ALLEXCEPT ( Book, Book[Customer Id] ) )
   VAR endDate =
      CALCULATE ( LASTDATE ( Book[Date] ), ALLEXCEPT ( Book, Book[Customer Id] ) )
RETURN
IF (
    Book[Date]
        = LOOKUPVALUE (
            Book[Date],
            Book[customer id], [Customer Id],
            Book[Date], startDate
        ),
    "Onboarding",
    IF (
        Book[Date]
            = LOOKUPVALUE (
                Book[Date],
                Book[customer id], [Customer Id],
                Book[Date], endDate
            ),
        "Offboarding",
        "Existing"
    )
)
```